# Extract posts from Drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have a website (for which I don't have access but I have the database and the website on my local drive) that was made in Drupal and which I need to update. Since I have no experience working in Drupal, I decided to do a new website in PHP (Laravel) but I have to add the posts that are already in the Drupal website. There are sections in the website of which each has it's own posts.

I found where the posts are in the Drupal database, in the `node` and `node_revisions` table. But the problem is that I can't find a way to figure out which post is in which section. Hoe does Drupal differentiate these posts?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say the posts are divided up into sections? Are you referring, for example, to the sections contributed omdule (https://www.drupal.org/project/sections)? Might also be helpful to post your database schema.

Comment: I guess "pages" could be a better word instead of "sections". It's a website for a math society and they have lectures, news, contests etc. and each one of those has it's own posts which I can't differentiate in the database. About the schema, sure, here you go: http://i.imgur.com/Kx63S82.png :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't discern much from a fuzzy screenshot with overlapping windows showing about 30 percent of the schema. How about a nice SQL file? Also, do you have access to the codebase for the site? If so you can read some PHP in the page callback to understand how posts are being pulled from the database. This is by far the easiest way to understand how to extract and re-implement.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into drush node export. It might save you some time. You can export all nodes to a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

"sections" probably is another node field where is stored node category.
Try to search for any of the "section" value in DB. Then you will see relation with nid from node table.